# ibeo lidar 4L setup

Tags: sensor, autonomous, lidar

I am having difficulties in finding information regarding ibeo lidar sensor power connection.

Lidar has 3 inputs/outputs one is Ethernet, CAN and power terminal.

As CAN only needs 4 pins (high out, high in, low out, low in) other 4 pins were connected to a DB9 and sharing the same DB9 adapter.

In my first experiment I will power the Lidar by using the DB9 (don't need CAN data) and obtain data using Ethernet.

However, after powering 12 V and connecting Ethernet cable to a HUB, Lidar IP wasn't found when pinging.

Does anybody knows good place to read material about this kind of experiment or if there is something wrong in my setup idea?

Best regards

Comment: Manufacturer documentation.

Comment: Ibeo seems to make more than one Lidar.  So, yup, ask the manufacturer.  Check their online documentation.  Check the documentation you got with the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ibeo Lux manual is not that complete and this other one from [SICK](https://cdn.sick.com/media/docs/3/03/803/Operating_instructions_LD_MRS_3D_LiDAR_sensors_en_IM0032803.PDF) is more complete so I found that it needed to be connected with 24V and 1.5A current, however didn't test it.